# Run installed .bin program

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu

I installed a .bin program but have no idea how to run it. (Xubuntu 20.04 LTS 64 bit)
https://www.postsignum.cz/files/ps_tool/pstoolplus_221_linux_x64.bin
Installed into home directory, can open the location but don't know how to open the actual program.

Answer (score 0):

That is a script that you have to run to actually install the program.  You can determine this by using the `file` command on that file:

```
 pstoolplus_221_linux_x64.bin: POSIX shell script executable (binary data)
```

So, try running it as `bash ./pstoolplus_221_linux_x64.bin` to start the installation process.  (It seems to be a `sh` script, so maybe you need to use `sh` and not `bash`.  I'm not interested in installing this program, so I don't intend to try myself.)  I'm not sure if you have to use administrator privileges by prepending `sudo` on to this.  Either way, I hope this is a program from a trusted source...especially if you intend to run it under `sudo`.

If you've done all this already, then I wouldn't know where the program has been installed to.  You'll have to look at the documentation or web page for this program to find out.  If you know the executable that's generated, you can see if it's in your path by putting `which` in front, but if you don't know the executable name, then you need to look at the documentation.

Comment: Thanks All for help so far, it is a trusted source - it's a program used by pharmacists in czech republic to issue digital prescriptions, and it it is build for linux, or so it claims. I made it executable and installed into home directory, but do not know how to start it, in bin there is no shortcut either. /home/andrej/PostSignumToolPlus/

Answer (score 0):

**First a warning**: be  very careful downloading executable files from the internet. Make sure you can trust the download before attempting to run it.

That aside, if this is a **trusted binary** that is compiled to run on your linux system, and it is a stand-alone executable (i.e., there are no other files it needs to access in order to run), then you can execute it by typing the file path of the binary file in the terminal. For this to work, the file must be marked to be executable, i.e., **the executable bit must be set**.

So first, you may need to set the executable bit. For example, if your file is in the Downloads folder, you will be able to set the file executable with the command:

```
chmod +x ~/Downloads/pstoolplus_221_linux_x64.bin
```

You can also set the executable bit of a file using your file manager.

To **run the file**, just type the full path and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
~/Downloads/pstoolplus_221_linux_x64.bin
```

You can also use a relative path to run the fike. For example, if you are in your home directory, you can run it with:

```
Downloads/pstoolplus_221_linux_x64.bin
```

If your working directory *is* the Downloads folder, then this will work:

```
./pstoolplus_221_linux_x64.bin
```

To run the executable just by typing the name, `pstoolplus_221_linux_x64.bin`, the executable must be in a folder that is in your **search path**. `echo $PATH` will show you the search path. It is a list of folders where the system will look for matching executables if you type a name of an executable, i.e., a "command", at the terminal.

In Ubuntu, the folders `~/bin` and/or `~/.local/bin` will automatically be included in your path. Thus, if you want to conveniently execute a binary by just typing its name, move it to one of these folders. You need to create them because they do not exist by default.